# Логирование сущностей с типом table type

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Дано:** Переменная типа user-defined table type (UDTT). Заранее не известно какого именно UDTT переменная, и, следовательно, не известно количество полей.

**Задача**: При возникновении ошибки в хранимой процедуре производится логирование всех её входных параметров для будущей реконструкции запроса и повторении ошибки (Для её устранения). С параметрами обычных типов нет проблем. Но что делать если у нас параметр того самого UDTT типа, где не известно ни количество полей ни количество записей. Как его логировать?

Для логирования есть 2 таблицы. Одна таблица содержит общую информацию об ошибке и имеет примерно следующую структуру:

```
error_id | login_id | date_insert | error_message
```

А для логирования параметров используется вторая таблица следующей структуры:

```
error_id (FK на первую таблицу) | parameter_name | value
```

**Окончательная формулировка вопроса:** Как мне во вторую таблицу (для логирования параметров) засунуть каждое значение каждой ячейки того самого UDTT, чтобы в будущем гененировать скрипт который повторит вызов процедуры с ошибкой.

Надеюсь теперь понятная суть вопроса.

**Предполагаемое решение:** Представить значение каждой ячейки нашего UDTT в виде одной строки используя оператор `for xml` и функцию `value`. И хранить значение всего табличного типа в виде одной строки. А при реконструировании запроса просто парсить эту строку используя какие-то заранее оговоренные спецсимволы. В принципе это решение. Но я надеялся услышать какие-то более удобные решения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сохранение содержимого переменной табличного типа в `xml` видится вполне разумным решением. Вроде бы этот момент не должен вызвать каких-то сложностей. Достаточно, например, использовать конструкцию `for xml raw`:

```
create procedure dbo.MyProc
(
    @tableParam dbo.UDTT readonly
)
as
begin
    set nocount on;

    declare @xml xml = (
        select *
        from @tableParam
        for xml raw, root('table')
    );
    select @xml;
end
```

Т.е. сохранить UDTT в `xml`, не перечисляя явно имена столбцов, вполне возможно.

Загрузка из `xml` обратно в UDTT, без явного перечисления имён и типов столбцов последнего, также возможна. Для этого можно использовать конструкцию `openxml` с опцией `with <ИмяТаблицы>`:

```
declare @tableParam dbo.UDTT; -- пустая переменная заданного типа
declare @xml xml;
select @xml = value from ... where ...; -- загружаем xml из лога

declare @xmlHandle int;
exec sp_xml_preparedocument @xmlHandle output, @xml;

-- создаём временную таблицу с набором и типами столбцов как у dbo.UDTT
select top (0) * into #DummyUDTT from @tableParam;

-- openxml загрузит xml данные, полагаясь на имена и типы столбцов #DummyUDTT
insert into @tableParam
select * from openxml(@xmlHandle, '/table[1]/row') with #DummyUDTT;

exec sp_xml_removedocument @xmlHandle;

drop table #DummyUDTT;

select * from @tableParam;
```

Естественно, определённые ограничения существуют при таком подходе.

Comment: Сложностей с этим подходом никаких и не возникло. Просто думал что есть какое-то более разумное решение. В любом случае спасибо за ответ. Остановлюсь пожалуй на этом варианте.